# Copy Root Multisite Site

Tags: multisite

I have a Multisite installation created in WordPress hosted at `example.com` with websites at `example.com/site1`, `example.com/site2` etc.

Is it possible to create an exact copy of `example.com` at `example.com/site3`?

[Blog Copier](http://wordpress.org/plugins/blog-copier/) and [NS cloner](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-cloner-site-copier/) don't allow you to ever create a copy of the root site for some reason. What would the technical limitations behind this be?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. This is the feature I wrote during the last days for the pro version of Multilingual Press.

One problem is that `wp_upload_dir()` does not always return the correct values after calling `switch_to_blog()`, that makes attachment copies unnecessary difficult. Besides that most things are simple. `TRUNCATE` the new blog’s tables and replace them with the content of the source blog, then update the values which are different.

Things get tricky when you need new relationships between some selected blogs, but all that is not special for the root site.

Comment: So copying the attachments from the root site to another site is more difficult then from one site to another because of unreliability in the `switch_to_blog()` function? Should WordPress, or the plugin authors fix this?

Comment: I think this is a WordPress bug. I haven’t found the time to narrow it down yet. Once I do that, I will write a proper report and probably a patch.